# compare two arrays in javascript and delete the object that both arrays have

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, javascript-objects

I have 2 arrays:

```
0: {id: 2, name: "TMA"}
1: {id: 3, name: "Hibbernate"}
```

```
0: {id: 1, name: "FB.DE"}
1: {id: 2, name: "TMA"}
2: {id: 3, name: "Hibbernate"}
3: {id: 4, name: "Event.it A"}
4: {id: 5, name: "Projket 2"}
5: {id: 6, name: "Projekt 1"}
```

I want to compare them and delete the objects with the id 2 and 3 cause both arrays have them and thats the similarity.

This is my Code so far:

```
const projectListOutput = projectsOfPersonArray.filter(project => data.includes(project));
        console.log(projectListOutput);
```

But every time i run this projectListOutput is empty.

Comment: are both arrays sorted?

Comment: When you mean bay sorted with the sort() function, then yes.

Comment: Which array is `projectsOfPersonArray` and which is `data`? Because if the short one is `projectsOfPersonArray`, then you've filtered both elements out...

Answer (score 2):

When using `includes` dont compare objects, Just build `data` as array of strings. Remaining code is similar to what you have.

```js
arr1 = [
  { id: 2, name: "TMA" },
  { id: 3, name: "Hibbernate" },
];

arr2 = [
  { id: 1, name: "FB.DE" },
  { id: 2, name: "TMA" },
  { id: 3, name: "Hibbernate" },
  { id: 4, name: "Event.it A" },
  { id: 5, name: "Projket 2" },
  { id: 6, name: "Projekt 1" },
];

const data = arr1.map(({ id }) => id);
const result = arr2.filter(({ id }) => !data.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare different objects, so every object is unique.

For filtering, you need to compare all properties or use a JSON string, if the order of properties is equal.

```js
var exclude = [{ id: 2, name: "TMA" }, { id: 3, name: "Hibbernate" }],
    data = [{ id: 2, name: "TMA" }, { id: 3, name: "Hibbernate" }, { id: 1, name: "FB.DE" }, { id: 2, name: "TMA" }, { id: 3, name: "Hibbernate" }, { id: 4, name: "Event.it A" }, { id: 5, name: "Projket 2" }, { id: 6, name: "Projekt 1" }],
    result = data.filter(project =>
        !exclude.some(item => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(project))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to the next:

```
const source = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "FB.DE"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "TMA"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Hibbernate"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Event.it A"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Projket 2"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Projekt 1"
  }
]
const toRemove = [{
    id: 2,
    name: "TMA"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Hibbernate"
  }
]

/**create object where keys is object "id" prop, and value is true**/
const toRemoveMap = toRemove.reduce((result, item) => ({
  ...result,
  [item.id]: true
}), {})

const result = source.filter(item => !toRemoveMap[item.id])
```

You can make function from it:

```
function removeArrayDuplicates (sourceArray, duplicatesArray, accessor) {
  const toRemoveMap = duplicatesArray.reduce((result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [item[accessor]]: true
  }), {});
  return sourceArray.filter(item => !toRemoveMap[item[accessor]])
}

removeArrayDuplicates(source, toRemove, 'id')
```

Or even better, you can make it work with a function instead of just property accessor:

```
function removeDuplicates (sourceArray, duplicatesArray, accessor) {
  let objectSerializer = obj => obj[accessor];
  if(typeof accessor === 'function') {
    objectSerializer = accessor;
  }
  const toRemoveMap = duplicatesArray.reduce((result, item) => ({
    ...result,
    [objectSerializer(item)]: true
  }), {});
  return sourceArray.filter(item => !toRemoveMap[objectSerializer(item)])
}

removeDuplicates(source, toRemove, (obj) => JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` array probably does not contain the exact same object references than `projectsOfPersonArray`. Look at the code below:

```js
[{ foo: 'bar' }].includes({ foo: 'bar' });
// false
```

Objects look equal, but they don't share the same reference (= they're not the same). 
It's safer to use `includes` with primitive values like numbers or strings. You can for example check the ids of your objects instead of the full objects.

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you merge two sorted arrays

```
var arr1 = [
  { id: 2, name: 'TMA' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Hibbernate' },
]
var arr2 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'FB.DE' },
  { id: 2, name: 'TMA' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Hibbernate' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Event.it A' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Projket 2' },
]
function mergeArray(array1, array2) {
  var result = []
  var firstArrayLen = array1.length
  var secondArrayLen = array2.length
  var i = 0 // index for first array
  var j = 0 // index for second array
  while (i < firstArrayLen || j < secondArrayLen) {
    if (i === firstArrayLen) { // first array doesn't have any other members
      while (j < secondArrayLen) { // we copy rest members of first array as a result
        result.push(array2[j])
        j++
      }
    } else if (j === secondArrayLen) { // second array doesn't have any other members
      while (i < firstArrayLen) { // we copy the rest members of the first array to the result array
        result.push(array1[i])
        i++
      }
    } else if (array1[i].id < array2[j].id) {
      result.push(array1[i])
      i++
    } else if (array1[i].id > array2[j].id) {
      result.push(array2[j])
      j++
    } else {
      result.push(array1[i])
      i++
      j++
    }
  }
  return result
}

console.log(mergeArray(arr1,arr2));
```